# Problemas para pasar las pruebas con Travis

Tags: reactjs, github, travis-ci

Problema al desplegar la aplicación en gh-pages con react js. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar este error? La solución mostrada debajo no funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Traduce por favor pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Estoy intentando ejecutar mis test de integracion continua con travis ci, pero me sale esa traza de error y he probado bastantes cosas pero no funciona nada, tambien he intentado hacer la solucion que se propone en la captura pero tampoco funciona, alguien sabe a ¿que se puede deber este error?

Comment: La traducción va en tu pregunta, edita por favor

Comment: Ya está cambiado.